# Why do I get this error: /system/bin/sh: ./mksquashfs: not executable: magic 7F45?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, squashfs

As I could not get mksquashfs tool for android. I compiled it for arm using cross compilation and got it built, toolchain is same for kernel as well mksquashfs.

I pushed mksquashfs to `/data/ partition of target`.

```
#: cd /data/
#: mkdir xyz
#: ./mksquashfs xyz xyz.sqsh
```

Error message is:

```
   /system/bin/sh: ./mksquashfs: not executable: magic 7F45
```

Please let know how to get a working mksquashfs for android, if I am missing any cross compile toolchain etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic number 7F45 specifies the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF) file type, a format that is not executable on ARM processors.

Reason could be either improper cross compilation or either using wrong toolchain.

Using correct toolchain should fix this problem